# Clip using Discard and Preserve option in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, clip

I am currently using QGIS, but it seems like there is no option like in ArcMap for Cliping polygons where I can choose if I want to Discard or Preserve selected area.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ArcMap in this case, but I think you could use "Difference" to get what what I suspect to be the "Discard" case in Arcmap.